# "UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile" Not Working In Animation Array, I need it to so that the memory is reduced

Tags: ios, arrays, animation, uiimage

I have multiple animations on my view controller, when I play them the memory goes extremely high, around, "450mb", I have been looking into ways to stop this.

One way I have seen is instead of using;

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"origami_panel"]
```

to load the image, using;

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010065"] ofType:@"png"]],
```

should reduce the overall memory used.

However, it does not? My memory still goes up the to what seems to be the exact same amount as when I used "imageNamed" for every image.
My full code for this animation and it's array is this;

```
//Panel 1 Animation
    NSArray *panel1Frames;
    panel1Frames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010001"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010002"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010003"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010004"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010005"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010006"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010007"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010008"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010009"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010010"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010011"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010012"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010013"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010014"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010015"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010016"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010017"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010018"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010019"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010020"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010021"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010022"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010023"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010024"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010025"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010026"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010027"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010028"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010029"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010030"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010031"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010032"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010033"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010034"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010035"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010036"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010037"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010038"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010039"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010040"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010041"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010042"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010043"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010044"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010045"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010046"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010047"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010048"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010049"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010050"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010051"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010052"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010053"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010054"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010055"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010056"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010057"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010058"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010059"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010060"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010061"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010062"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010063"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010064"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010065"] ofType:@"png"]],
                    nil];
    panel1Image.animationImages = panel1Frames;
    panel1Image.animationDuration = 2.6;
    panel1Image.animationRepeatCount = 1;
```

Please can someone tell me what I have down wrong? Or perhaps there is a better way to do this? I tired to research "dealloc" but couldn't find what I needed, perhaps that would be better?
Thanks.

Comment: `imageNamed` loads and caches the image whereas `imageWithContentsOfFile` reloads the image every time from file. so that shouldnt make any difference.

Comment: Sadly, if it has made a difference, it hasn't made a large enough one. Is my code correct here then? It also plays a sound, is there code that loads contents of file with a sounds, for example, soundWithContentsOfFile?

edit** I just removed the sound from the action so that just the animation was started and it still provoked a large memory.

So do you with the code above that imageWithContentsOfFile should be working for me?

Comment: There is no such method named `soundWithContentsOfFile `. However to play short audio sound you might use AudionToolbox.framework as documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't be using stringWithFormat: here, since you already have a string.

Comment: I have used the code below, it make my animation a lot more streamlined, however, I still have the memory issue, any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

`UIImage` has a class method named `animatedImageNamed:duration:`. You provide a named pattern of images, like `@"origami_panel0100"` and it will load all available images automatically. You should use that as it is more optimized than loading each individually.

Example:

Say you have images named like so:

Anim1.png
Anim2.png
Anim3.png
Anim4.png
...
Anim999.png

You create the animation sequence by:

`UIImage* animatedImage = [UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"Anim" duration:20];`

This creates a `UIImage` objects which represents an animation. You provide this image to your view, and it will be drawn animated.

More on this method in the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/animatedImageNamed%3aduration%3a).

Comment: This sounds great, I'm new to Xcode, please could you provide a little more code to your answer? I can't quite understand it.

Comment: I will add an example.

Comment: Something like?



UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"origami_panel00001,png",@"origami_panel00002.png" duration:3;

Thank you very much, your example will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, you provide the name without the count at the end, and it will find the images automatically.

Comment: So what if I wanted many images one after another? Would I put another line of code with the next image referenced and the time I want that image to show for? My animation is 25 frames a second so each image would show for 0.04 seconds.

Comment: You calculate the total time of the animation. If the animation length is 1 second, you tell the method. It will calculate how much time each frame has to be displayed to achieve this result.

Comment: So does this method know that load all images start with the name "Anim" and it knows to play anim1 then anim 2 etc? I'm sorry I don't quite understand how the method works in relation to referencing all of the images

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43630/discussion-between-leo-natan-and-rob-swish)

Comment: Although this code is more streamlined, I am finding it very hard to find out how to stop it from looping, BUT **MOST IMPORTANTLY** IT DOES NOT FIX MY MEMORY ISSUE.

Comment: I only used caps and bold to hopefully get the answer of someone else, not to be mean to you Leo, you were very helpful.

Comment: No worries. I still think the issue is from elsewhere. You should use Instruments as discussed in the chat.

Comment: I will. I will have to learn how to interpret what the answers mean that the instruments give me. At least, by doing your method, and it still having the problem, we know that it is not to do with my array, as it still did it when I used your more refined code. I have even started again and I still get these issues. **Is there a way after my array has played to unload the images from the cache?**

Comment: **I THINK I KNOW MY PROBLEM** Although I am using "[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"origami_panel010001"] ofType:@"png"]]," I am telling the NSArray to alloc, is there a way to rewrite my code so it is not telling the nsarray to alloc?

Comment: You always alloc. That's not the problem.

Comment: Ahh darn, it was just I check another thread and it said something about it but wasn't talking about Arrays.

Comment: 504mb was taken up by VM:ImageIO_PNG_Data, I assume this is all of the images being taken up by the five animations once i have played them all through once? The total file size of all of these images is 15.5mb, so I don't see how this is possible?

Comment: I got this from the documentation, "You take ownership of an object if you create it using a method whose name begins with “alloc” or “new” or contains “copy” (for example, alloc, newObject, or mutableCopy), or if you send it a retain message. You are responsible for relinquishing ownership of objects you own using release or autorelease. Any other time you receive an object, you must not release it."

Comment: So how do I release my array? Im using ARC.